# Why is the Rado–Milner paradox considered a paradox, anyway?

Tags: cardinals, ordinals

The cardinality of $\alpha$ (where $\kappa\le\alpha<\kappa^+)$ is equal to $\kappa$ anyway. Why should it be a suprise that I can "pack" $\alpha$ into a countable number of boxes, each of a size no bigger than $\kappa^n$ ? Of course I have to use the right sequence when picking the elements from $\alpha$ when doing that (i.e. exploiting the bijection between $\alpha$ and $\kappa$).

Comment: I'm not sure the first sentence makes sense?

Comment: What does cardinality have to do with it, seeing as the "size" in "size no bigger than $\kappa^n$" is order type and not cardinality?

Comment: Anyway, if it surprised Milner and Rado but it doesn't surprise you, that just means you have better intuitions about ordered sets than they did.

Comment: I mean, you have better intuitions about ordered sets than **whoever gave that theorem the name "Milner–Rado paradox"**. (I guess that probably wasn't Milner and Rado themselves.)

Comment: @bof: Indeed, the Rado-Milner paradoxon (see for example [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milner%E2%80%93Rado_paradox)) does not claim, that the Xn have a cardinality <= K^n, but rather that the ordinality is <= k^n. But that does not appear to to change much, since card(Xn)<=type(Xn).
Thanks for your encouragement that I might be simply right.